# Automatic Convert and Delete Filetype Server Error (Timing Out?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a script that will convert xls documents in a folder to sheets versions, then delete the xls versions. The script works, but because I have plenty of xls files in this folder, I believe it's timing out because it is throwing up, "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 6, file "Convert XLS")" error a little while after I start running it. Is there a way to execute this without the server timing out or something?

```
function convertXLS() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('File_ID');
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});
  }
 // while (files.hasNext()) {
//    Drive.Files.remove( file.getId());
//} 
  }
```

Update:

So I reconfigured the code to this:

```
function importXLS(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('File_ID');// you can also use a folder as starting point and get the files in that folder... use only DriveApp method here.
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY);
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xls')>-1){ // this check is not necessaey here because I get the files with a search but I left it in case you get the files differently...
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = { title : name+'_converted',
                     key : ID,
                     'parents':[{"id":"File_ID"}]
                    }
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
        convert: true, 
      });
    }
  }
}
```

But now it's giving me this error, "API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Internal Error (line 14, file "Convert XLS")" after about two minutes of it running. I don't know what to do :(

Comment: My experience is that creating and deleting files takes a while.  If you have a lot of files to do, I'd do it in batches.  With a timebased trigger or a trigger from the client side.

Comment: Correct, creating a deleting file take a while. If you're basic google user, script maximum time execution is 6 min.

Comment: Oh ok. How do I divide a single function into batches? Im new to using drive api and scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are facing is a time-out due to the execution limit for Apps Script.

To solve this, create a function that converts and deletes a single file, then run it multiple times.

To do that, you will use [`getFilesByType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByType(String)) in conjunction with [Advanced Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) with the `Drive.files.insert`  function with options as `{convert:true}`.

Running it multiple times can be done with a time-based trigger and/or manually.

Since you will be getting files only of a specific MIME Type, when you run out of XLS files you should have no problems.

Hope this helps!